# What happened to the Senkai Gates during Inoue's kidnapping?

Tags: bleach

In the Hueco Mundo arc, Episode 139, 19th minute, the passage between gates should be closing from behind but the narrowing of the passage wasn't approaching and though Inoue stayed there for a lot of time and chatted with Ulquiorra while he cuts down Inoue's escorts and she waits and heals them. Such a long time taken and no threat of narrowing of gates till then? What happened suddenly? Why?

Comment: Are you talking about the passages that they open through Hueco Mundo and Human world? why are they keeping them so long open?

Comment: No! The one that they opened from soul society to send Inoue to the human world and she was kidnapped by Ulquiorra! Episode 140! @pap

Comment: But she is already kidnapped, in which minute?

Comment: Sorry! It was int he previous episode at 19th minute! @pap

Comment: So you are talking about the Dangai, she was in with the 2 shinigami escorts. Right?

Comment: Yes i'm talking about that part! @pap

Comment: The passage never closed, because that never happens. The only thing that in Dangai exist to "punish" the invaders, is Kōtotsu. The Senkai Gates we are assuming were closed and the other gate (Human World) to be opened it had to be done by one of the 2 shinigamis, as Byakuya have done in the first epiosdes.

Answer (score 1):

The passage doesn't close because they had hell butterflies with them. Hell butterflies are used for both communication as well as keeping the gates from collapsing while they are in them.

Comment: Where is it said so?